# Use movement vector to detect impact in 2D field

Tags: algorithm

Given a coordinate and a movement vector. How can I get the list of all blocks will be infected?

I think it's a little bit like "object in view" or "object collision"?

For example, the original point *O* is (2, 2), the movement vector *"→"* is (0, 1) and the blocks *B* should be [(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 3), (3, 4)]

```
 0123 y→
0.......
1...BB..
2..O→B..
3...BB..
x.......
↓.......
```

If the movement vector is (-1, 1), the *B* should be [(0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4)]

```
 0123 y→
0..BBB..
1...↗B..
2..O.B..
3.......
x.......
↓.......
```

I'm currently considering

```
point P (x, y) vector V (v, u)
x' = x + v
y' = y + u
set S = ([x'-1, x'+1], [y'-1, y'+1])
calculate a line L "y=ax+b" perpendicular to V crossing (x', y').
split S into two groups by L
chose the one V is facing
```

but I cannot find a way to achieve last two steps.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: You should look at the Bresenham line drawing algorithm. It's designed to go between two points rather from a point in a direction, but it's easily modified to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something called `time-until-impact` or `time-until-collision` or something like that.

But in most game engines this is not the way to go. What a **standard** technique for collision handling is, is space partitioning. That means, if you have `n` rigid bodies in your simulation then a naive algorithm requires `n^2` checks (each with another) to see if a collision happened. However, performance-wise this is a killer. Instead you should partition your space via (`uniform partitioning, Oct-Trees, Z-ordering, etc.), then you only check with neighboring rigid bodies that are neighbors with the cell in question.

Note, that the velocity vector (what you call movement) vector is not really needed here because in practice it brings no benefits.